# .NET MVC Core dependency injection with generics

Tags: entity-framework, generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I've started some playing around with .NET MVC Core after using the previous versions on .NET MVC and its going ok so far. I've been a bit lazy and never really got round to using any dependency injection containers, but I'm having a bash with the built in DI container in MVC Core.

The problem I'm having is with generics... I've got a generic repository interface and I've implemented this in a generic repository class. I've now extended this class in a couple of places to do various things and I'm trying to now use this extended repository in DI into the controllers constructor.

So...

```
interface IRepository<TContext, TModel>

class GenericRepository<TContext, TModel> : 
    IRepository<TContext, TModel>

    where TContext : DbContext
    where TClass : class
```

The ExtendedGenericRepository is as follows - ignoring the extra methods I added of course. Note that 'MyDbContextClass' extends 'DbContext' (i.e. Entity Framework) and implements my own 'MyDbContextInterface':-

```
    public class ExtendedGenericRepository<TContext, TModel> : 
        GenericRepository<TContext, TModel>        

        where TContext : MyDbContextClass
        where TModel : MyModelClass
    {
        public ExtendedGenericRepository(IMyDbContextInterface context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
```

Now I've got another class into which I'm trying to inject this as follows:-

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(IExtendedGenericRepository<IMyDbContextInterface, IMyModelInterface> repository)
    {
    }
}
```

In my StartUp.cs I've got the following (I've left out everything else):-

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped(
           typeof(IMyDbContextInterface),
           typeof(MyDbContextClass)
        );

        services.AddScoped(
           typeof(IExtendedGenericRepository<,>),
           typeof(ExtendedGenericRepository<,>)
        );

        services.AddScoped(
           typeof(ISomeClass),
           typeof(SomeClass)
        );
    }
```

So in the controller I've now got this:-

```
public class SomeController :
    Controller
{
    public SomeController(ISomeClass someClass)
    {
    }
}
```

All the other stuff I've registered for DI in the StartUp.cs ConfigureServices has worked great. I'm sure I'm probably getting something wrong or completely missing something. I'm also guessing (maybe incorrectly) that the DI container will instantiate my 'someClass' and all the cascading classes that I've also registered as services - I'm just not sure if what I'm doing is right or if there is a better way...

Anyway running the thing like this I just get an error message saying that the TContext constraint has been violated, but I can't see how (its probably something right under my nose that I've missed! :)

Can anyone help?

Comment: I can't see the registration of `IMyModelInterface` service in your `ConfigureServices()` method

Comment: Also the `ExtendedGenericRepository<,>` class does not implement the `IExtendedGenericRepository<,>` interface according to your code. Before posting a question, please try to prepare a separate project to reproduce the issue, ensuring it doesn't have syntax errors and irrelevant classes. I think DI tries to instantiate `ExtendedGenericRepository<IMyDbContextInterface, IMyModelInterface>` and that really does violate the TContext constraint on `ExtendedGenericRepository`. Your constraints should be specifying interfaces for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had missed those things so added them but still got the error about context constraints. I reverted to making the extendedgenericrepository non generic and now it works fine. I'll keep trying but thanks for the help